# How to use a JMP instruction within C code with C8051F120 microcontroller

Tags: c, inline-assembly, keil

I am trying to write some code for a C8051F120 Silicon Labs microcontroller. During the initialization routines, I would like to check for a flag that gets set whenever a newer version of firmware has been uploaded to address 0x2000 of the microcontroller's code space. If the flag is set, I would like to jump to the code space that contains the latest firmware version. I am writing all of my code in C and using the Keil compiler through Silicon Laboratories IDE. Since there is no "JMP" equivalent instruction in C, I am attempting to use an in-line assembly instruction to accomplish the task, as shown by the simplified example code below.

```
//main.c
#include "jmp_UpdateSpace.c"
void main(void) {
    if(download_flag){
        jmp_UpdateSpace();
    }
}

//jmp_UpdateSpace.c
void jmp_UpdateSpace() {
    #pragma asm
    JMP 0x2000;
    #pragma endasm
    return;
}
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to accomplish this task? I know there are different flags I can set for the compiler, assembler, and linker within Silicon Labs IDE but I haven't been able to find the right combination yet. I keep getting errors from the C51 Keil compiler that say:

*** ERROR C272 IN LINE 17 OF jmp_UpdateSpace.c: 'asm/endasm' requires src-control to be active

*** ERROR C273 IN LINE 17 OF jmp_UpdateSpace.c: #pragma asm/endasm not allowed in include files

*** ERROR C272 IN LINE 19 OF jmp_UpdateSpace.c: 'asm/endasm' requires src-control to be active

Comment: Doesn't Keil also support GNU C inline asm syntax, like `asm("jmp 0x2000");`?  I don't use keil tools, but I've never seen `#pragma` for inline asm.

Comment: @Peter Keil does support inline assembly and I just tried using  `asm("LJMP 0x2000);`. However, when I try to run the SiliconLabs IDE debugger, it just skips past that command instead of executing it.  It compiles with no errors and I see the following in my .SRC file created from the C file:

`LCALL _Timer3_Init;`
`//jmp_UpdateSpace();`
`__asm("LJMP 0x2000");`
`("LJMP 0x2000");`